# Liquid nested if statement

Tags: if-statement, nested, liquid

This statement should only return goals scored if the value is higher than zero, but it's returning it regardless:

```
{% for member in site.data.members %}
<div class="player">
    {% if member.goals > 0 %}
        <span class="goals">{{ member.goals }}</span/>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

### EDIT

Thanks Shadowen, here is my site.data.members file, it is just a CSV:

```
name,position,goals,photo
Joe Bloggs,goalkeeper,0
James Denver,midfielder,2
Edward Martins,forward,0
Tom Kirk,defender/midfielder,0
Carl Swanson,striker,0
Orry Michaels,defender,0
Chris Smith,midfielder,0
```

Comment: If more information is needed, this is a Jekyll site build using Windows 7

Comment: The most obvious information that would be requested is: What is in `site.data.members`? Provide the file or dump the variable with `{{ site.data.members }}`.